# Drawing in a video

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, video, draw

I am doing an exercise in which the program has to follow that routine: when the user clicks on any point of a video, it gets that pixel and turns all pixels in a range of 5% into red. Since it is a video, I am saving the points (x,y) the user clicks in a list and making the retangle for every point. Here is the code: import numpy as np import cv2

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


cap =cv2.VideoCapture(-1)

 #creates list


lista= []

    #mouse callback function

def getpixel(event,x,y,flags,param):

       #adds point (x,y) in pixels ont the current list

if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    lista.append([x,y])
    print (x,y),img[x][y]


  while(cap.isOpened()):

 ret,img= cap.read()
 if ret:
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    cv2.setMouseCallback('image',getpixel)
 i=0
 #draw the retangle
 while i<lista.__len__():
       img[int(0.95*lista[i][0]):int(1.05*lista[i][0]),int(0.95*lista[i][1]):int(1.05*lista[i][1])]=(0,0,255)
       i+=1
 if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
    break

    cap.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have already checked and it is creating the list, adding the points and entering in the "while" part of the code. However, I can't see the retangles. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

*Note*: For a quick fix read this answer from bottom.

In your code you calculate percentage NOT frow `width` / `hight` of the captured picture but from the *points themselves*:

```
img[int(0.95*lista[i][0]):int(1.05*lista[i][0]), ....
```

So you need to obtain the `width` and `hight` - something as

```
width  = cap.get( CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH )
height = cap.get( CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT )
```

and then the vertices of your rectangle adjust to these values:

```
int( lista[i][0] - 0.95 * width )
int( lista[i][0] + 1.05 * width )
int( lista[i][1] - 0.95 * hight )
int( lista[i][1] + 1.95 * hight )
```

To be specific and more elegant:

Instead of this part of your code

```
i=0
#draw the retangle
while i<lista.__len__():
    img[int(0.95*lista[i][0]):int(1.05*lista[i][0]),int(0.95*lista[i][1]):int(1.05*lista[i][1])]=(0,0,255)
    i+=1
```

write this:

```
width  = cap.get( CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH )
height = cap.get( CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT )

deltaX = 0.05 * width
deltaY = 0.05 * hight

while point in lista:
    ltX = int (point[0] - deltaX)        # Left top X coordinate
    ltY = int (point[1] - deltaY)        # Left top Y coordinate
    rbX = int (point[0] + deltaX)        #   --- and so on ---
    rbY = int (point[1] + deltaX)

    img[ltX:rbX, ltY:rbY] = (0,0,255)
```

Comment: Please consider to accept my answer (click on the check mark) if it was useful for you (2 reputation for you).